# Possible to have `validate` fail on not specified elements?

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, ecmascript-6

The below returns success, even though `obj` contains an element that is not in the schema.

**Question**

Is it possible to have [validate](https://github.com/eivindfjeldstad/validate) fail, when it sees elements that are not specified in the schema?

[Jest](https://jestjs.io/) have this `expect(obj1).toEqual(obj2)`.

If Validate can't do it, what options do I then have to detect unwanted elements?

```
const Schema = require("validate");

const obj = {good: "1", bad: "2"};

const user = new Schema({
  good: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  }
});

const r = user.validate(obj);
console.log(r);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a `strict` option on the `Schema`, from the [documentation](https://github.com/eivindfjeldstad/validate#schema-1):

> ##### Schema
>
> A Schema defines the structure that objects should be validated against.
>
> ###### Parameters
>
> - `obj` schema definition
> - `opts` options
>
>   - `opts.typecast`
>   - `opts.strip`
>   - **`opts.strict`**
>
>     **Validation fails when object contains properties not defined in the schema**
>     <sup>(optional, default false)</sup>

So you'll need something like:

```js
const options = { strict: true };

const user = new Schema({
  good: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  }
}, options);
```